# Data is empty on re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I have two components and using react-select for Dropdown

In component(Home), i created a dropdown and getting data from hook(useHome). When first load, i am calling api and from api result, i am showing only 50 items in dropdown.

```
<Select
onInputChange={(value) => filterVehicleModels(value)}
options={vehicleModels} 
/>
```

But on input change i want to filter data from hook and show in dropdown. But it is not working. Every time when input change, i am getting empty array because of rendring.
here is my function in hook:

```
const filterVehicleModels = (inputValue) => {
    if (tempFilteredModelList.length) {
      let tempAirports = [];
      if (inputValue.length > 1) {
        tempFilteredModelList.filter((i) => {
          if (i.label.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue.toLowerCase()))
            tempAirports.push(i);
        });
      }
      setVehicleModels(tempAirports);
    }
};
```

I stored data in tempFilteredModelList when i call api.

Can you tell me how can I have data?